# Как перефразировать предложение?

Tags: стилистика

"...работы других мастеров, которые, несомненно станут для вас источником вдохновения в творчестве". Тут не понятно, к чему относится "которые": к мастерам или работам. Как можно изменить предложением, чтобы таких сомнений не возникало?

Comment: Для начала надо написать предложение полностью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пунктуация неверная у вас. Надо так: *"...работы других мастеров, которые, несомненно, станут для вас источником вдохновения в творчестве"* Перефразировать ничего не надо, ибо и так понятно, что мастера вряд ли могут стать источниками вдохновения. Очевидно, что речь идет о работах. Но если хотите перефразировать, то вот вам такой вариант: "...работы, которые написаны другими авторами и которые, несомненно, станут для вас источником вдохновения в творчестве..."
P.S. Непонятно - одно слово.

Comment: Пожалуй, перефразированное предложение стало более тяжеловесным! Так что, действительно, не надо ничего менять. Если, конечно, фраза не предназначена для "машинного" перевода.

Answer (score 0):

Чем выше рейтинг - тем выше организация поднимается в списке организаций по своей тематике при результатах поиска.